# round brackets in xaml syntax

Tags: wpf, xaml, rounding, brackets, coloranimation

when I'm using ColorAnimation to change Background of control i'm using following syntax:

```
<ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" 
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
 To="Black" />
```

I'm very happy it works but I couldn't find any information about round braces in xaml syntax reference ...

So could you please explain where does this syntax come from and what does the round brace actually mean?

It would be very helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please see [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx):

> The parentheses indicate that this
>   property in a PropertyPath should be
>   constructed using a partial
>   qualification. It can use an XML
>   namespace to find the type with an
>   appropriate mapping. The ownerType
>   searches types that a XAML processor
>   has access to, through the
>   XmlnsDefinitionAttribute declarations
>   in each assembly. Most applications
>   have the default XML namespace mapped
>   to the
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation
>   namespace, so a prefix is usually only
>   necessary for custom types or types
>   otherwise outside that namespace.
>   propertyName must resolve to be the
>   name of a property existing on the
>   ownerType. This syntax is generally
>   used for one of the following cases:
>
> - The path is specified in XAML that is in a style or template that does
>     not have a specified Target Type. A
>     qualified usage is generally not valid
>     for cases other than this, because in
>     non-style, non-template cases, the
>     property exists on an instance, not a
>     type.
> - The property is an attached property.
> - You are binding to a static property.