# What is the Relevence of Braces in an XAML Binding Path Declaration

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

All, the question is a simple one. The following binding does *not* work, that is, the ascociated `Trigger` does not fire

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.IsAnyTextMatch, 
    ElementName=dataGrid}" Value="false">
```

to fix this and make the binding work, we place the binding reference in braces, as follows

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.IsAnyTextMatch), 
    ElementName=dataGrid}" Value="false">
```

Why does adding the braces resolve the reference/binding problem and what is going on?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The answer to this related question should help:

[round brackets in xaml syntax][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640573/round-brackets-in-xaml-syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Multiple Property (Indirect Property Targeting)**

```
<Binding Path="propertyName.propertyName2" .../>
```

`propertyName` must resolve to be the name of a property that is the current `DataContext`. The path properties `propertyName` and `propertyName2` can be any properties that exist in a relationship, where `propertyName2` is a property that exists on the type that is the value of `propertyName`.

**Single Property, Attached or Otherwise Type-Qualified**

```
<object property="(ownerType.propertyName)" .../>
```

The parentheses indicate that this property in a `PropertyPath` should be constructed using a partial qualification. It can use an XML namespace to find the type with an appropriate mapping. The `ownerType` searches types that a XAML processor has access to, through the `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` declarations in each assembly. Most applications have the default XML namespace mapped to the http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation namespace, so a prefix is usually only necessary for custom types or types otherwise outside that namespace. `propertyName` must resolve to be the name of a property existing on the ownerType. This syntax is generally used for one of the following cases:

1. The path is specified in XAML that is in a style or template that does not have a specified Target Type. A qualified usage is generally not valid for cases other than this, because in non-style, non-template cases, the property exists on an instance, not a type.
2. The property is an attached property.
3. You are binding to a static property.

For use as storyboard target, the property specified as propertyName must be a `DependencyProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because The Binding cannot determine the complete Expression you want to bind to. If you put it into braces the complete expression (with namespace etc.) can be determined correctly.

If you write `(dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.IsAnyTextMatch)` with braces the markup parser will take your whole binding as ONE expression. Otherwise it would stuck trying to bind to `dataAccess:`. With braces you will have an explicit statement that this is **one single expression**

I hope you finall got me :)

Comment: Yes, but _why_? Why do the braces make the difference? This is the definitive difference between the two syntaxes, but you answer does not address this fact...